# How to count how often elements appear together in a dataframe, and sum the values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi-index dataframe with accounting data that looks like this:

[image]

Where indexes are:

- MANUAL_JOURNAL_ENTRY - with 2 possible values,
- DOCUMENT_NUMBER - unique values,
- GL_ACCOUNT - repeating values, but unique per document

And AMOUNT_IN_LOCAL_CURRENCY is a value column, that is split on Debit and Credit based on values from 'DEBIT_CREDIT' column.

I want to find how often elements from GL_Account appear together as a group (in the same document), and sum up the value from debit and credit respectively.

I have found a fairy acceptable way to find the count of the unique groups, but it does not seem very performance efficient and I've lost the information about Credit and Debit.

```py
df.groupby('DOCUMENT_NUMBER')['GL_ACCOUNT'].apply('_'.join)).reset_index(name='Lists').groupby('Lists').size().reset_index(name='count')
```

Edit: Numpy (or other) level solutions are acceptable, as performance is relevant.

Desired output something like:

[image]

sample [dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F60ItfEFGtevxSXK-RAw8xHASG1zymZlbmq96COVSWc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: It is not clear if AMOUNT_IN_LOCAL_CURRENCY is an index or not.

Comment: No, it is not an index